# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "myschema" already exists

Tags: h2

The issue is when I execute my integrations tests I get the exception :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "myschema" already exists; SQL statement:
    CREATE SCHEMA myschema [90078-196]
```

I have this application-test.yml :

```
debug: true

spring:
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        enabled: true
  jpa:
    database: h2
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema
    username: sa
    password: 
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

hbm2ddl is set as create-drop changing it to update would solve your issue.